# CSS Animation not working correctly with JavaScript Variables from PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, css, json, animation

I have a script that gets an array of objects from PHP...

I am able to output the results of the script into Div's to display on my site.

Next i have some CSS animations, The animation only occurs if the length of the variable is greater than the div width... The problem i have is that the animation is not working when i incorporate my script with the CSS animations but it does work in this JSFiddle test below:

http://jsfiddle.net/Musicman/4Rhxm/5/
**(i have this working in FIREFOX only at the moment but will ad the other browser support later)**

In the test you can see that i have created a couple of variables, one which is shorter than the div width and one that is longer than the div width. Everything is working correctly and the information that is longer than the div width is bouncing back and forth as expected.

Below is my problematic script, It gets an array of objects from a JSON encoded PHP array. The Function **"getPlayList"** loops through the elements of the JSON objects and i use **"document.getElementById"** to name the elements so that they can be used in my HTML code, then a timer is set to refresh every second...

But when i use **my** script the variable information is displayed but there is **no animation** but when i emulate my script in the JSFiddle seen above everything works as expected, i am a little lost as to why this is happening but the issue seems solely to do with **my** script:

**MY SCRIPT**

```
function getPlaylist() {
    var xmlhttp,
    timer;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

    try {
        var list = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        if (list && typeof list === 'object') {

            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

                var currentItem = list[i];

                document.getElementById("list0artist").innerHTML=list[0].artist;
            document.getElementById("list0title").innerHTML=list[0].title;

            }

       }

    } catch(e) {

        throw new Error("Bad response...");

    }

}
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "playlist.php?t=" + Math.random(), true);
xmlhttp.send();

timer = setTimeout(getPlaylist, 1000);
}
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.... Thanks !

**UPDATE:**

Below is my HTML & CSS code for the actual script, i use "body onload" to load the script variables into html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<script src="/testsite/AlternativeSecondPlaylist.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {
    width: 257.4px;
    height: 41.85px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #383838;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 41.85px;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: baumans;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position:relative;
    }
.nowPlayNoAnimate {
    position:absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nowPlayAnimate {
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-name: slidein;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes slidein {
    from {
        transform:translateX(0);
    }
    to {
        transform:translateX(calc(-100% + 257px)); /* -100% + parent width */
    }
}

</style>
<body onload="getPlaylist()">

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="list0artist" class="nowPlayNoAnimate"></div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="list0title" class="nowPlayNoAnimate"></div>
</div>

<script>
var animate = document.getElementsByClassName('nowPlayNoAnimate');

for (var i = 0; i < animate.length; i++) {
    if (animate[i].parentNode.offsetWidth < animate[i].offsetWidth) {
animate[i].classList.add("nowPlayAnimate");
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure you are executing the animation script **after** you fill the `list0artist` and `list0title` elements?

Comment: oh also making an ajax request every second is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut i have updated my question and added my html code for the actual script....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your animation script only executes once whereas your ajax call executes every second. since the second time getPlaylist() executes, whatever your animation script changes reverts back and you need to run them again like this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

    try {
        var list = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        if (list && typeof list === 'object') {

            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

                var currentItem = list[i];

                document.getElementById("list0artist").innerHTML=list[0].artist;
                document.getElementById("list0title").innerHTML=list[0].title;
                var animate = document.getElementsByClassName('nowPlayNoAnimate');

                for (var i = 0; i < animate.length; i++) {
                    if (animate[i].parentNode.offsetWidth < animate[i].offsetWidth) {
                        animate[i].classList.add("nowPlayAnimate");
                    }
                }
            }
       }

    } catch(e) {

        throw new Error("Bad response...");

    }

}
};
```

Also I strongly suggest, not to send an ajax request ever second, since this could slow your server down significantly. suppose you have 1000 people who has your page open in a browser tab for 12 hours, you'll have 100 requests / second just from that.

Comment: you are the man... thank you for explaining this... Also.. the timer will eventually be based upon the song length from the server and will only refresh when the song ends.... I understand that that many requests would burn my server out

Comment: I have one small issue, if text is too big for div then the text will animate... GOOD!!, but when a new variable is sent to the page the page remembers the old "nowPlayAnimate" Class and continues to animate even if the text is too small to need to animate... how can i tell the page to revert back to its original condition of "nowPlayNoAnimate" CLASS without having to refresh the page.. Hope that makes sence! Thank You!!

Comment: put `animate[i].classList.remove("nowPlayAnimate");` on else condition

Comment: haha... i tried an else statement but i was trying to re-add the "nowplaynoanimate" ... thanks for the .classList.remove lesson!!!!